# which way is better when using getline?

Tags: c++, c++11

When reading from a file, we have two ways to

Way 1:

```
ifstream fin("data.txt"); 
const int LINE_LENGTH = 100; 
char str[LINE_LENGTH];  
while( fin.getline(str,LINE_LENGTH) )
{    
    cout << "Read from file: " << str << endl;
}
```

Way 2:

```
ifstream fin("data.txt");  
string s;  
while( getline(fin,s) )
{    
    cout << "Read from file: " << s << endl; 
}
```

which is better? Personlly, I prefer way2 since I don't need to specify max length, what's your comments?

Comment: Way 1 uses magic numbers, so Way 2. They do different things though. You're often going to want to use Way 2 because you don't care about lengths, you just want to extract data separated by delimiters. Apples and oranges.

Comment: Way 2 is more idiomatic C++. Use it unless you have good reason not too.

Comment: The first way you've shown is mostly a relic from the days before `std::string` had been invented. The only way I can imagine using it today would be if I needed to write code for some ancient compiler that simply didn't support the second.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin Way 1 (limited line length) does prevent a nefarious user from entering a _huge_ line in some attempt to hack the system.

Comment: @chux: limiting line length can be useful, but if/when you need to do so, there are better ways than that to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Way 2 is better (more idiomatic, avoids hard-coded lengths that could break parsing).  I'd write it slightly differently:

```
for(string s; getline(fin,s); )
{    
    cout << "Read from file: " << s << endl; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**std::getline** and **istream::getline** are from different interfaces and accept different types of parameter.

Particularly for your case, I would agree that it is more convenient to use **std::getline(fin,s)**.

Comment: why using for loop here?

Comment: @Adam Lee I think you're referring to the answer below, not mine. Anyway I would say it's logically doing the same thing - initialization; condition checking; increment (blank in this case), though you may find while loop literally makes more sense.